# Given 101 Colored Balls, prove that there are 11 balls of the same color or 11 balls of different colors

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Given 101 Colored Balls, prove that there are 11 balls of the same color or 11 balls of different colors.

My approach:
I'm assuming that there are **no** 11 balls of the same color then trying to prove that there are 11 balls of different color and vice versa.

I feel like I have intuition to the solution, like in the first direction (what I stated above) If I try to divide the balls of the same color into groups I need at least 11 groups

I'm struggling to write stuff formally, any suggestions on how to apply the **pigeonhole principle** in this question?

Comment: Have you heard of the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Well, if there were only $10$ or fewer colors and no more than $10$ of each color...what's the largest number of balls you could have?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yeah, I'm trying to use it in this question but I'm not figuring out how

Comment: @lulu a 100 that's right. i'm trying to figure out a way to use the pigeonhole principle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group each type of colored ball in groups of $10$

$\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{10}\boxed{?}$

Then the $101th$ colored ball  has to be either the same as one of the $10$ colors placed or else a $11th$ color in the box marked $?$

Thus given $101$ Colored Balls,it is proved that there are either $11$ balls of the same color or $11$ balls of different colors.

---

**Response to OP's comment**

If we go strictly by the original definition of the pigeonhole principle, each hole can accomodate only one pigeon, but we can extend it, as I did in the answer for simplification, putting $10$ balls of one color in one hole.

If you want more formality, have $100$ holes and   fill the holes to the maximum allowed of each color to reach $100$, and thus prove  that the $101th$ pigeon is *necessarily*  either one from already placed $10$ colors, or a new colored pigeon.

I don't see any need to make it more "formal"

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.
How can the pigeonhole principle be applied formally here?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are only balls of $10$ or fewer colours, then can you use pigeonhole principle and get $11$ balls of some colour?